# Magento redirects from onepage to cart in Firefox and Safari (ipad)

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, shopping-cart

Ok, I'm having this issue where in Firefox on a desktop and Safari on an iPad the url checkout/onepage redirects to checkout/cart. So from the actual checkout process to the cart again. Even if I manually type in checkout/onepage I just get redirected to the cart again. Magento, PHP, and Apache are not throwing any errors in the entire process or warnings.

Site: www.cepcompression.com
Magento Version: 1.7.0.2

Edit: Found out that if I turn off Secure Frontend URLs it works fine but then again I can't turn them off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, turns out that turning off Session IDs in the URL caused the issue to break the checkout for some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

At My machine I can easily add product into add to cart  and go to the checkout. I will also check in Mozilla and safari.

you can see the below screen

[image]